# TensorFlow strange memory usage

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, gpu, memory

I'm on an Ubuntu 19.10 machine (with KDE desktop environment) with 8GB of RAM, an i5 8250u and an MX130 gpu (2GB VRAM), running a Jupyter Notebook with tensorflow-gpu.

I was just training some models to test their memory usage, and I can't see any sense in what I'm looking at.  I used KSysGUARD and NVIDIA System Monitor (https://github.com/congard/nvidia-system-monitor) to monitor my system during training.

1. As I hit "train", on NVIDIA S.M. show me that memory usage is 100% (or near 100% like 95/97%) the GPU usage is fine.
2. Always in NVIDIA S.M., I look at the processes list and "python" occupies only around 60MB of vram space.
3. In KSysGUARD, python's memory usage is always around 700mb.

There might be some explanation for that, the problem is that the gpu's memory usage hits 90% with a model with literally 2 neurons (densely connected of course xD), just like a model with 200million parameters does. I'm using a batch size of 128.

I thought around that mess, and if I'm not wrong, a model with 200million parameters should occupy 200000000*4bytes*128 bytes, which should be 1024gb. 
That means I'm definitely wrong on something, but I'm too selfless to keep that riddle for me, so I decided to give you the chance to solve this ;D

PS: English is not my main language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tensorflow by default allocates all available VRAM in the target GPU. There is an experimental feature called memory growth that let's you control that, basically stops  the initialization process from allocating all VRAM and does it when there is a need for it.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental/set_memory_growth

Comment: Ok, that means all my VRAM is being allocated to tensorflow, even if he uses like 1mb of all the 2GBs. That means, that my problem is that the tensorflow process is not shown by the system monitor, resulting in a process wich is not on the list that actually occupies all the memory. ...right?

Comment: Ok, I found out how memory works. But there's still one things I'm not sure about: how am I able to train so large models (250million parameters) on only 2GB of vram?

Comment: Tensorflow has to fit the neural network, the data, etc in memory so the model you are training is still within your 2GB VRAM limit.

Comment: @DennisOrlando if my post answered your question you can accept it.